# How do I completely remove fade function from this code? I know this is very basic but I'm a complete noob

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
(function(){
      var words = [
          'Your vision made a reality.',
          'Your brand made scrollable.',
          'Your story made clickable.',
          ], i = 0;
      setInterval(function(){
          $('#changingword').fadeOut(function(){
              $(this).html(words[i=(i+1)%words.length]).fadeIn(0);
          });
      }, 1000);
        
  })();
</script>
```

Tried deleting the whole fadeOut function along with fadeIn but doesn't work that way.

Comment: Change `fadeOut` to `hide`. Then it will hide the element immediately, instead of fading.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

```js
(function(){
      var words = [
          'Your vision made a reality.',
          'Your brand made scrollable.',
          'Your story made clickable.',
          ], i = 0;
      setInterval(function(){
              i=(i+1);
              $('#changingword').html(words[i%words.length]);
      }, 1000);
        
  })();
```

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to in your code?